# Is there a way to apply an onclick event to multiple values in xslt?

Tags: html, xslt, onclick

I am trying to apply an onclick event on multiple values  obtained from a for-each in xsl.

My code display all the "ville" (City) from an xml document. It also displays all "lycee" (high school) that belongs to each "ville", as a href.

What i want is to display the list of all "eleves" (students) belonging to a "lycee" when i click on this specific "lycee". In order to do that i used an onclick event tied to a function that toggle visibility.
But the function (hide/show) only works for the first "lycee". 
When i click on the other lycee it seems to impact only the visibility of the first lycee's student list, not their own list.

````xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="villeKey" match="eleve" use="ville" />
<xsl:key name="lyceeKey" match="eleve" use="lycee" />
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <style>


.hidden {
     display:none;
}


  </style>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" >      

function toggle_visibility(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block')
           e.style.display = 'none';
        else
           e.style.display = 'block';
   }


</script>
</head>
  <body>
  <h2>Villes</h2>
  <xsl:for-each select="eleves/eleve[count(. | key('villeKey',ville)[1]) = 1]">
    <xsl:sort select="ville" />
    <b style="color:Tomato;"><xsl:value-of select="ville" /> </b>,<br /><br />

                <xsl:for-each select="key('villeKey', ville)[count(. | key('lyceeKey',lycee)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="lycee" />
                      <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">  <xsl:value-of  select="lycee" /> </a> <br /> 
                       <div id="foo" class='hidden' >
                <xsl:for-each select="key('lyceeKey', lycee)">

                            <xsl:sort select="specialite"/>
                           <p>  <xsl:value-of select="nom"/> &#160; <xsl:value-of select="prenom"/> </p>   

                        </xsl:for-each>
                       </div>

                </xsl:for-each><br /><br />

  </xsl:for-each>

  </body>
  </html>



</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

```xsl
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different ids instead of the same `foo`you have used, so change

```
       <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">  <xsl:value-of  select="lycee" /> </a> <br /> 
       <div id="foo" class='hidden' >
```

to

```
       <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('{generate-id()}');">  <xsl:value-of  select="lycee" /> </a> <br /> 
       <div id="{generate-id()}" class='hidden' >
```